# Ms sql объеденить две таблицы без связи

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы. В первой имеем:

```
1
2
3
```

Во второй:

```
ф
Ы
В
А
П
Р
```

Как получить следующую выборку:

```
1:ф
2:ы
3:в
 :А
 :П
 :Р
```

Comment: Что здесь строки, а что столбцы?
Какой критерий соединения?

Comment: а порядок записей в таблицах как задавать, надо же какой то order by дать ... Еще очень интересно зачем бы это могло понадобится

Comment: Скажим так, это нужно ждя неадекватного отчета. Цифры и буквы это строки. Ордер бай вообще не имеет значения.

Comment: Задача, связать 2 не связанные таблицы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала записи надо пронумеровать по порядку (придется задать некий порядок следования), а потом связать по этим номерам строк:

```
select ColumnX, ColumnY
  from (select ColumnX, row_number() over(order by ColumnX) rn
          from Table1
       ) A
  full outer join 
       (select ColumnY, row_number() over(order by ColumnY) rn
          from Table2
       ) B
      on A.rn=B.rn
```

Comment: Отлично! То что нужно!