# запрос с выводом данных с разных таблиц в одну независимо друг от друга

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Есть 2 (или более таблиц), которые не связаны между собой. Нужно вывести данные этих таблиц (в моем случае по одному столбцу с каждой) в одной таблице. Пусть это будет поле Id, тогда результат должен будет получиться таким

t1.Id / t2.Id

1 / 100

2 / 123

3 / 345

4 / null

5 / null

Значения null во втором столбце означают, что записи во второй таблице закончились.

Повторю на всякий случай, таблицы не связаны, джойнить их нечем.

Comment: Что значит *нечем джойнить* ? делать JOIN можно не зависимо от связей. Вашу выборку можно получить `SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: @4per, я же русским по белому написал, таблицы не связаны. То что в примере id совпадают - это случайность. На самом деле наборы id могут быть другими (1,2,3,4,5) и (100,123,234) соответственно для таблиц

Comment: @4per, готово. Исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *Oracle* можно было бы использовать

```
select 
  q1.id, q2.id
from
  (
  select 
    t1.id, rownum rn 
  from t1
  ) q1
full join
  (
  select 
    t2.id, rownum rn 
  from t2
  ) q2
on q1.rn = q2.rn
```

Порядок строк, разумеется не гарантируется.

<s>В *SQl Server* нет аналога `rownum`, насколько я знаю. Я бы предложил добавить в таблицы поле, которое будет выполнять данную функциональность. Но это, конечно, увеличение хранимого объема таблицы.</s>

Comment: В MSSQL есть нумерация строк. Спасибо, я попробую ваш способ чуть позже. Выглядит логично.

Comment: Для MS SQL уже был такой вопрос-ответ, принцип разумеется тот же: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577753/ms-sql-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8/577761#577761

Comment: @iRumba, забыл написать, что порядок не гарантируется