# Выборка из двух таблиц - Select LEFT (INNER) JOIN без повторов слева

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задача на MS SQL.
В качестве примера своей проблемы, привожу две простые таблицы: штатное расписание и работники. Нужно сопоставить работников штатному расписанию.
Особенность в том, что в данном примере 3 должности одинаковые(код32) и на них     нужно сопоставить 3 работника как раз с этими должностями (код 32). Единственные связи между таблицами это КодДолжности (Dol) и КодПодразделения (Otdel). Поле Fam (Фамилия) в таблице WorkTable - уникальное. Id у обоих таблиц в связях никак не участвуют, - уникальные для записей.

Имеем:

Таблица штатного расписания
DolTable:
Id| Otdel|  Dol|    Fam
431|    4819 |  32 |    0
432|    4819 |  32 |    0
433|    4819 |  32 |    0

---

Таблица работников
WorkTable:
Id  |   Otdel|  Dol|    Fam
1521|   4819 |  32 |    Иванов
1522|   4819 |  32 |    Сидоров
1523|   4819 |  32 |    Петров

---

Нужно вывести только 3 строки так:

Id |    Otdel|  Dol|    Fam
431|    4819 |  32 |    Иванов
432|    4819 |  32 |    Сидоров
433|    4819 |  32 |    Петров

Как ни пробовал сделать такую выборку, не получается.
Мучил запрос вида:

```
SELECT * from DolTable as dt   
LEFT JOIN WorkTable as wt ON ((dt.Dol = wt.Dol)and(dt.Otdel = wt.Otdel))
```

Но пока получаю 3 строки, которые повторяются трижды = 9 строк.

Нужно вывести без повторов.

В будущем, вместо SELECT хочу делать Update поля Fam в таблице DolTable по этому же принципу.

Попытаюсь быть понятней. Добавлено:

---

Таблица штатного расписания
DolTable:
Dol|    Fam
32 |    0
32 |    0
32 |    0

---

Таблица работников
WorkTable:
Dol|    Fam     | Name    |
32 |    Иванов  | Иван    |
32 |    Сидоров | Cергей  |
32 |    Петров  | Петр    |

---

Нужно вывести только 3 строки без повторов так:

Id |    Otdel|  Dol|    Fam     | Name
431|    4819 |  32 |    Иванов  | Иван
432|    4819 |  32 |    Сидоров | Сергей
433|    4819 |  32 |    Петров  | Петр

Суть вопроса именно в том, чтобы SELECT LEFT JOIN делал выборку без повторов слева.

Comment: Сделайте GROUP BY

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста кодом, как применить здесь GROUP BY для поля Id в таблице DolTable.

Comment: А что хранится в таблице `DolTable`? Должности? Почему тогда поле `Dol` там?

Comment: По сабжу - либо используйте `INNER JOIN`, либо при использовании `LEFT JOIN` используйте условие выборки `WHERE`

Comment: В таблице DolTable поле Dol это код должности. В таблице WorkTable это тоже код должности. Расшифровка кодов должностей идет  в отдельной таблице, но не в DolTable. DolTable это типа штатного расписания.

Comment: Какая то у вас странная схема. у работника должен храниться не код должности, а его id. А при такой схеме как сейчас вообще ничего понять нельзя. почему работнику 1521 должна быть подобрана должность именно 431, а не 432 например ? И что делать если у вас 4 работника и только 3 должности с кодом 32, последнему 4-му ничего не ставить в соответствие или взять одну из имеющихся. А если должностей наоборот больше чем работников, как в таком случае выбирать ? В общем думаю надо считать что связи нет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/577761/194569 можно доп. partition добавить и клеить по коду

Comment: Id поле не учитываем, никаких связей между двумя этими таблицами это поле не имеет, -значения рандомные, это просто уникальный код записей в таблицах. Фактически связь между таблицами в этом примере, это только поле Dol.

Comment: @impervald но вы не ответили на остальные вопросы, что делать если записей разное количество и какую из записей все таки сопоставлять. И посмотрите ссылку что я дал, там практически готовый ответ на ваш вопрос, других путей решения проблемы все равно нет (если вас конечно не устроит вариант, что у всех сотрудников будет 431)

Comment: В моем случае, работников не может быть больше, чем должностей. Однако, если работников будет меньше, чем должностей, то тогда в результате третья строка из выборки будет 433| 4819 | 32 | NULL | NULL.   Смысл в том, что есть определенный список должностей в отделе и я назначаю на него работников. Причем в отделе может быть несколько одинаковых должностей. И тогда по всем свободным должностям в таблице DolTable где код =32 нужно распределить всех работников из таблицы WorkTable, у которых код должности =32. Id в таблице DolTable у одинаковых должностей разные.

Comment: *привожу две простые таблицы: должности и работники* Ну бред же... То, что Вы назвали таблицей Должности, на самом деле есть таблица ШтатноеРасписание. Которая должна ссылаться на таблицу Должности, в которой НЕТ дублирования. Т.е. в показанном примере будет 1 запись в таблице Должности и 3 записи в таблице ШтатноеРасписание. А Работники соответственно должны ссылаться не на таблицу Должности, а на конкретные записи таблицы ШтатноеРасписание, связью 1:1.

Comment: Akina, верно  DolTable - это штатное расписание, я некорректно написал, назвав ее таблицой должностей. Вообщем у меня есть большой объем данных работников с кодами должностей и подразделений, а также штатное расписание с кодом должностей и подразделений, Мне нужно укомплектовать это штатное расписание используя в качестве связи код Должности и КодПодразделения и пометить в штатном расписании поле Fam фамилией работника.

Comment: Вот именно. Поле Dol этой таблицы должно ссылаться на ID в таблице должностей, которая не показана (если вообще существует). А на поле Id этой таблицы должно ссылаться поле Dol таблицы работников. Чтобы понять суть, добавьте в таблицу DolTable поле с размером оклада Salary - с РАЗНЫМИ окладами...

Comment: Распределять должности между работниками нужно не запросом, а какой-то внешней логикой. И вот уже после того, как эта логика отработает, у каждого работника будет уникальный айдишник должности, который и должен храниться для работников вместо неуникального кода должности.

Comment: Моя логика заключается сейчас в том, что я делаю выборку из двух таблиц через  LEFT JOIN. Все отлично сопоставляется, но дублируется, если в подразделении есть одинаковые должности.  А суть проблемы в этой логике, как мне убрать повторяющиеся записи слева при LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на почти готовый ответ и написал, что другого пути все равно нет. Ok, поправил тот пример под ваше название таблиц, написал тут ответом, но отличия от того ответа по ссылке минимальны ...

Comment: Mike, очень интересное предложение использовать Row_Number, пытаюсь сейчас разобраться и вникнуть в этот код...

Comment: @impervald Наша проблема в том, что нет уникальной связи, нумерация записей в дополнение к номеру отдела дает нам эту уникальность

Comment: Mike, ваше решение работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select D.id, W.Otdel, W.Dol, W.Fam
  from (
    select w.*,
           row_number() over(partition by Otdel order by id) RN
      from WorkTable w
  ) W
  left join(
    select Otdel, Id,
           row_number() over(partition by Otdel order by id) RN
      from DolTable
  ) D ON D.Otdel=W.Otdel and D.RN=W.RN
```

пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7cdd2/2)

Вообще сопоставлять по фамилии нельзя, она явно не уникальна. Любая связь таблиц должна быть по их первичному ключу, которым обычно является id. Поэтому на основе этого запроса update должен писать в штатное расписание id работника, который занял эту должность.

Comment: Да, Mike, Fam это будет как уникальный Id работника. Изучаю ваш код, напишу сразу, как разберусь в нем.

Comment: @impervald Fam - это фамилия? она неуникальна, вполне могут быть два работника с одной фамилией. Заведите отдельный числовой id.

Comment: @impervald Если у вас будет работать Иванов Иван Иванович и на работу решит устроиться еще один Иванов Иван Иванович, вы ему откажете в приеме на работу, в связи с тем, что уже работает его полный теска ?

Comment: Я некорректно в примере написал, в Fam у меня уникальные  Integer значения работников, надо  было все таки не писать фамилии, чтобы это не вводило всех в заблуждение. Mike, в любом случае, ваше решение уже проверено и работает, большое Вам спасибо!