# Объединение нескольких запросов в один

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Можно ли из 3 разных запросов объединить в один, если они не связаны? Чтобы в одном `select` была примерно такая информация:

```
t1.name|t1.count|t2.name|t2.count|t3.name|t3.count
```

Comment: `id` в таблице есть? Вам в любом случае придётся присоединять к чему-либо, иначе без указания соединения `select` выдаст кучу пар t1, t2, t3.

Comment: А если в первой таблице 2 записи а во второй 3, то как определить какую запись рядом с какой надо показывать и что делать с лишними записями ?

Comment: @Mike автор, видимо, хочет как в Excel присоединить значения - где-то null, и столбец идёт уже без данных, при этом в соседнем столбце есть значения.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577753/194569 Правда для MySQL с версией до 8.0 придется нумерацию строк делать через переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Вам в любом случае придётся присоединять, поэтому можно попробовать через нумерацию строк через переменную, пример:

```
select c.name, c.cnt,
    p.name, p.cnt,
    b.name, b.cnt
from
   /* Делаем нумерацию строк, с чем потом будем соединять */
    (select @curRow1 := @curRow1 + 1 AS row_number 
     from cheese JOIN (SELECT @curRow1 := 0) r
     union
     select @curRow2 := @curRow2 + 1 AS row_number 
     from potato JOIN (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r
     union
     select @curRow3 := @curRow3 + 1 AS row_number 
     from banana JOIN (SELECT @curRow3 := 0) r
    ) m

    /* Присоединяем по очереди таблицы */
    left join
        (select c.*,
            @curRowC := @curRowC + 1 AS row_number
         from cheese c
            JOIN (SELECT @curRowC := 0) r
         ) c on m.row_number = c.row_number

    left join
        (select c.*,
            @curRowP := @curRowP + 1 AS row_number
         from potato c
            JOIN (SELECT @curRowP := 0) r
         ) p on m.row_number = p.row_number

    left join
        (select c.*,
            @curRowB := @curRowB + 1 AS row_number
         from banana c
            JOIN (SELECT @curRowB := 0) r
         ) b on m.row_number = b.row_number
```

Пример вывода на бананах, сырах и картошки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[db-fiddle с бананами, сыром и картошкой](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dZffgijgFdy93mF4nxQws3/0)

Comment: то что надо, вот только в postgrese можно так же?

Comment: @ШкедАскет в PostgreSQL можно лучше.

Comment: у меня просто запрос из 3 таблиц, через inner join-ны, и через этот запрос я вывожу, группы за 1 курс и сколько там студентов. и в одной HTML таблицы 4 курса и таблицу в таблице не охота создавать, и вот можно ли 4 запроса где меняется только условие (1 курс, 2 курс, 3 курс,4 курс) соеденить в один SELECT

Comment: @ШкедАскет Опишите в тексте вопроса структуру БД (под вопросом ссылка "править"), покажите свой запрос и то, что вы хотите от него получить. Понять по написанному вами тексту что именно требуется вообще не представляется возможным

Comment: select t1,t2 from (select * from table) as t1, (select * from table2) as t2

Comment: только тут без join-нов, просто чтоб они не перемножались между собой. а просто соеденились. t2 к t1, по номеру строки допустим